# Android Spinner Narrow by Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, spinner, adapter

How can one narrow items in a spinner by keyboard input?

I am looking for the functionality seen in HTML select on Android. Basically, I have a spinner with multiple items (hundreds in my case) and I want to be able to narrow the spinner to items relevant to keyboard input. So, if I press "71", I will get items starting with 71....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a filter on the adapter for your Spinner. If you aren't using a custom adapter, you will most likely need to create one.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even see that a filter was needed. Android has this implemented in a silly fashion, in that it's forced onto HTML select in web apps, but I have to jump through hoops for similar functionality in a native app. Seems like this functionality should be chalked up in XML somewhere.

Comment: @27A That's a matter for debate.  IMHO, it's the right way to do it in a native app since if follows the MVC pattern and aids in "separation of concerns".  If Android was to implement it the HTML way, which is designed for a completely different paradigm, I would consider that to be silly.

Comment: i gotta go with simon on this one.

Comment: @Simon You're right in regards to MVC. I just don't think a purely MVC paradigm should stand in the way of _some_ automation, while I am sure Android already has some grey areas and qualms with MVC. It would just be a nice touch, and if necessary override the behavior.